# Convert a 'content document' to attachment (ideally in flow)

Tags: api, visual-workflow, files

I have a managed application that creates files (PDF) as content documents attached to a custom object (source).  I also have another object where files from another process are interfaced to the object as an 'attachment' (target).  These files are visible on a custom VF page that is visible externally to users.  Basically, any file attached to this object (as an attachment) is visible.  I can create a content document link via flow which creates a reference to this content document in the target but this doesn't work for me needs as its not an attachment (thus not visible on the VF page).  Is there a way to 'convert' a content document to an attachment, ideally in flow?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this installable extension will enable you to carry out the conversion in a flow: https://unofficialsf.com/new-flow-action-convert-files-to-attachments/